# How to integrate when the degree of the denominator is higher than the numerator?

Tags: integration

I need to solve

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}} +\sqrt[3]{x} +2} dx
$$
I tried by substituting
$$
\ u=\sqrt[3]{x} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x=u^{3} \ \ \ \ du=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x}} dx\ \ \ \ \ \ \ dx=\sqrt[3]{x} \ du
$$
Which gave me
$$
 \begin{array}{l}
\int \frac{3u^{2}}{u^{2} +u+2} du\ =3\int \frac{u^{2}}{u^{2} +u+2} du=3\int \left(\frac{u^{2} -\left( u^{2} +u+2\right)}{u^{2} +u+2} +1\right) du=\\
=3\int \left(\frac{-u-2}{u^{2} +u+2} +1\right) du=3\left(\int 1\ du-\int \frac{u}{u^{2} +u+2} du-\int \frac{2}{u^{2} +u+2} du\right)
\end{array}
$$

How do I integrate
$$
\int \frac{u}{u^{2} +u+2} du
$$

I tried following a procedure in my maths book and got
$$
\ln\left| u^{2} +u+2\right| -\left(\int \frac{u}{u^{2} +u+2} du+\int \frac{1}{u^{2} +u+2} du\right) +c
$$
Which doesn't really make sense to me. Help?

Comment: Move that first integral over to the other side to collect it with the other one, and the second integral can be evaluated using completing the square and trig sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to solve integrals of the kind $\int \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} dx$ where $p(x)$ is linear and $q(x)$ is a quadratic, is to express $p(x)$ as follows.

$$p(x) = Aq’(x) + B , \ c\in \mathbb R$$

In your question, $$u= A(u^2+u+2)’ +B = A(2u+1)+B = 2Au + A+B$$ Compare coefficients: $$2A= 1 \implies A=\frac 12 \\ A+B=0 \implies B=-\frac 12$$ and the integral reduces to $$\frac 12\int \frac{d(u^2+u+2)}{u^2+u+2} -\frac 12 \int\frac{du}{u^2+u+2} \\ = \frac 12\log|u^2+u+2|-\frac 12 \int\frac{du}{\left(u+\frac 12\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)^2} \\ =\frac 12\log|u^2+u+2| -\frac 12\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{u+\frac 12}{\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}}\right)+C \\  $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Partial decomposition can help much. Just find the roots of the denominator, namely $r_1,r_2$, and find proper coefficients $A$ and $B$ such that $${u\over u^2+u+2}={A\over u-r_1}+{B\over u-r_2}$$

An alternative way is to rewrite $$u^2+u+2=(u+{1\over 2})^2+{7\over 4}$$and substitute $$u+{1\over 2}={\sqrt7\over 2}\tan w$$and proceed with respect to $w$.